# Getting token from an URL string

Tags: regex, powershell, url, token

Im trying to get the token from an URL string.

Example URL (obviously altered not to post sensitive content):

```
https://example.com/file.extention?validation.token=kDa9udKcYp1Wo2ay5Lbb&parameter2=some_value
```

I'm trying to make a regex that will return only the token.

https://example.com/file.extention?validation.token=**kDa9udKcYp1Wo2ay5Lbb**&parameter2=some_value

I first search for "token=", which I then exclude from the result. For that I've tried non-matching groups and other solutions for that. However I'm currently landed on lookarounds. Then I match the token, which I want to return. This seems to be working. My problem is though, that the URL may or may not include more parameters. I therefore make another lookaround, saying that the token will either be followed by an "&", or be the end-of-(line/string) "$". This is the troublesome part.

My current regex:

```
(?<=token\=)([\w\d\S]*)(?=[\&|$])
Flags: gm (as of now)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/1EzmB2/1)

As the link shows, it works.... sort of. It doesn't work when the URL string only contains the token.

The token is 20 characters, so I've come up with the following variation:

```
(?<=token\=)([\w\d\S]{1,20})
Flags: gm (as of now)
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/ACaF6F/1)

That is working correctly, however I'm automating work processes, and the token might change in a future update, so I would like to do as little maintenance as possible.

Can it really be right that I cannot search for a string between "token=" and ("&" or "$" end-of-(line|string))?

#### Edit

There could be #anchors in the URL as well, which unintentionally could be included as a part of the token, if I'm just checking for the next ampersand. Also by doing this as some suggested, it could span through multiple lines as seen [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/POw2Wd/2).

Comment: This problem is much easier to solve as to not involve a regex at all. If you can tell us which language you want to solve , it might help somebody to post a code snippet

Comment: Try matching until you encounter an ampersand  [`(?<=token\=)([^&]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/POw2Wd/1)

Comment: @rajeshnair I've tagged the post with Powershell. Furthermore it is part of a CURL script.

Comment: Following your update, are you after `(?<=token=)([^&#]+?)(?=&|#)` ? Try [here](https://regex101.com/r/yVVWL0/2).

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built-in to .NET / PowerShell using the [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) and [HttpUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) classes:

```
$url0 = 'https://example.com/file.extention?validation.token=kDa9udKcYp1Wo2ay5Lbb';
$url1 = 'https://example.com/file.extention?validation.token=kDa9udKcYp1Wo2ay5Lbb&parameter2=some_value';

[System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(([uri]$url0).Query)['validation.token'];
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(([uri]$url1).Query)['validation.token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple split as well:

```
$str = 'https://example.com/file.extention?validation.token=kDa9udKcYp1Wo2ay5Lbb&parameter2=some_value'
(($str -split '&' -match 'token') -split '=')[1]
```

Comment: The "validation.token" may not always be the first parameter, otherwise I've just hardcoded it.

Answer (score 0):

You could match not an ampersand or a `#` in a negating [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^&#]+`

[`(?<=token\=)([^&#]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/yVVWL0/1)

Comment: There could be #anchors in the URL as well, which unintentionally could be included as a part of the token. I've forgot about that, I'll edit the post.

Comment: @SørenKjeldsen You can add the `#` to the character class.Can you add some example urls to the question?

Comment: You might also match the characters you allow in a character class [`(?<=token\=)([\w#]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/POw2Wd/3)

Answer (score 0):

Just for kix..

```
$url = "https://example.com/file.extention?validation.token=kDa9udKcYp1Wo2ay5Lbb&parameter2=some_value"
(ConvertFrom-StringData ([uri]$url).Query.Substring(1).Replace("&", [environment]::NewLine))['validation.token']
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments on your own attempts:

- The character class `[\w\d\S]` - `\w` (word character) includes digits, thus `\d` is redundant. Also, `&` is matched by the *none white space* class `\S`.
- The character class `[\&|$]` - No need to escape `&` in a character class and `$` in a character class means the literal character `$` - not *end of line*.

Try

```
token=(\w+)(?=&|$)
```

This gives you the token in capture group 1. I cant see you mention it, but I've assumed that tokens only can consist of letters and digit.

It's *similar* to UnbearableLightness suggestion, but performs about 10 times better. (Performance may not be an issue, but...)

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pD6aJc/1).

Comment: Yes but this solution does not work for url's which carry over the next line, as per op's latest update.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes it does. See the [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/pD6aJc/1). Or paste the RE into yours. That last edit is what my RE101 sample came from.